# Logging out from Trello Android app

Tags: trello, android

I'm using the Trello Android app and cannot find a way to log out.

This is troublesome since I have two accounts, one for work related boards and one for spare time collaborations.

I looked for logout function in regular Trello (which was semi-hard to find) but still have trouble logging out under the Android app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about a native Android app, which belongs on [android.se].

Answer (score 9):

Click the profile picture in the upper right hand corner, there should be a menu there with an option to log out. It's the last option.

[image: Profile Picture]

Comment: Thanks! The reason I was looking for it in the first place was I couldn't logout from the Android app. So my question really should have been: How do I find the logout function in the Android app?

Comment: @TorgnyRasmark that's a *key* part of the question you left out.

Comment: Of course! FYI,  I  almost immediately tried to rephrase my question but that was put on hold by some editorial function.
 I tried to find the solution to my logout problem by looking into Trello proper. Couldn't find it there either, so I asked. Now as that is resolved, and the solution didn't bring any light to the basic problem, I want to ask again: how to logout from Trello Android app?

Comment: I finally succeded in logging out from Android app: It's in the settings menu which is next to the profile picture, but only in the start screen. (I had trouble finding it since I expected a function in the GUI rather than a settings option:)